# How to install cordova in existing html project?

Tags: html, ios, xcode, cordova, apache-cordova

I have an html project that need to convert into xcode project. I am tried of creating new xcode project by using cordova successfully done but i want install cordova in a existing html project to create xcode porject.

Comment: html project means ? static website?

Comment: Why not the other way around: Create a new cordova project `cordova create com.mydomain.myproject`, add your platform `cordova platform add ios`, install some plugins (when needed), and copy your html/css/js/whatever files into the newly created project. Advantage: you still have a backup of the original project in case of issues.

Comment: @Calaris thanks for the answer, exactly  I'm working on it.